# Compile a .NET Core application as an EXE file using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I created a .NET Core application (v1.1) in Visual Studio 2017. When I compile it, I get a DLL file produced instead of the expected EXE file for the built project. I did check the `csproj` file and confirmed the output type is set to `exe`, but no dice.

Why is Visual Studio 2017 is still producing a DLL file?

I'm sure it's a quick setting somewhere that I forgot...

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Core.EF.SqlServer\Core.EF.SqlServer.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

**Update 2019:**

.NET Core 3.0+ projects will now include an executable for the platform you build on by default. This is just a shim executable and your main logic is still inside a `.dll` file.

But .NET Core 3.0 also introduced single-file deployments so deploying with

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=True --self-contained false
```

will create a single .exe file containing all your dependencies. You can change `--self-contained` to `true` to also include the .NET Core Runtime as well so .NET Core does not need to be installed globally on the target machine.

**Original**

.NET Core applications are supposed to be `.dll`files. `OutputType` set to `Exe` in this case means "executable" and does everything necessary to ensure that the output is runnable (entry point from `Main()` method, `.runtimeconfig.json` file). The resulting DLL file is meant to be run using:

```
dotnet yourapp.dll
```

This DLL file works across all platforms that are supported by the .NET Core runtime (Windows, Linux, and macOS). This is called a "portable" or "framework dependent" deployment.

If you want really a `.exe` file, consider self-contained deployments. This will create an output that contains its own copy of the .NET Core runtime and an `yourapp.exe` file - but it also increases the size of the published application and it needs to be updated when new versions of the runtime are released.

Also, the resulting application only works on the operating system published for.

Refer to *[.NET Core application deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002999)* for more details on the deployment options and how to set them up.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the different deployment strategies. That helped in my understanding of .net-core a bit more.

Comment: @Martin, I have been looking for "-p:PublishSingleFile=True" flag all my life in dotnetcore (1 month :)). Thankfully I am starting my dotnetcore life with 3.0 and this works great on OSX Mojave, Linux (CentOS 7.6), and Windows 10.

Answer (score 63):

In Visual Studio 2017:

1. Right click on your project and select Publish (In Visual Studio 2019, click on menu *Build* → *Publish <projectName>*)
2. Select 'Folder' and create a new profile
3. In tab 'Publish', click 'Configure...'
4. Select Deployment Mode: Self-contained, Target Runtime: win-x86 (or win-x64)
5. *Save*
6. *Publish*

In the folder <Your project>\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\win-x86\ you will see the EXE file:

[image: Publish settings]

Comment: Thanks! Good to know there is a way to do it in Visual Studio.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019, there is a "File publish options" section in this Profile Settings dialog. Click on it to expand it then make sure "Produce single file" is checked.

Answer (score 7):

Starting with .NET Core 2.2 you can build *framework-dependent executables*

---

Although building a self-contained deployment can be a good solution, it has its own drawbacks. (See R.Titov and Martin Ullrichs' answers on SCD-s.)

Fortunately, .NET Core 2.2 supports the building of so called *framework-dependent executable*-s, that are **essentially a wrapper binary (*.exe* on Windows) around the standard dll-s**.

This way **you have all the advantages** (and disadvantages) of the standard framework-dependent deployment (again, see Martin's answer), but **you have a convenient way to launch it**, without having to call it through the *dotnet* CLI.

You can publish your app as a *Framework-Dependent Executable* using the following syntax:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r <RID> --self-contained false
```

Where RID is the usual runtime identifier, e.g. `win-x64` or whatever platform you wish to build for ([see the catalog here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog)).

Answer (score 2):

That's how you do a self-contained publish with command-line in any OS:

```
dotnet publish C:\src\App\App.csproj -c release -r win-x64 -o output-win-x64
```

Besides, you might want to get the output decreased from typical ~60 MB for a simple Hello World app to ~30 MB by using *ILLink*.

Also, you might want to go further and get a single .exe file of a size at around 5 MB and use *ILCompiler*. [See this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44835273/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-console-application-run-using-only-a-single-file-in-ne/53743869#53743869).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that ILCompiler is an AOT compiler platform like CoreRT, which has its own limitations (no Reflection.Emit, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good, but what I find sometimes convenient is:

- Not have it self-contained because the target machine is likely to have .NET Core of the correct version installed. This cuts on number of the DLL files I need to ship.
- Not have to specify `dotnet` on the command line

For this, a bat file wrapper can be used, similar to these lines:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM see http://joshua.poehls.me/powershell-batch-file-wrapper/

SET SCRIPTNAME=%~d0%~p0%~n0.dll
SET ARGS=%*

dotnet "%SCRIPTNAME%" %ARGS%
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

If your application ends up in `yourapp.dll`, name the bat file `yourapp.bat` and place it along side the DLL file. Now instead of `dotnet yourapp.dll params` you can call `yourapp params`.

Note that the context of this answer is in-house tooling, so all the developers using the utility will have a pretty standard development machine setup. If this is to be distributed to an external customer who is running who knows what on their boxes, the self-contained option is far superior.