# How do I create an EXE output from a .Net Core console application project in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: .net, .net-core, console-application

Why, when I create a .NET Core Console Application project in Visual Studio 2017, does it output a DLL file instead of an EXE file?

Well, we know the answer to this and it's been well documented and addressed in other, very popular questions on Stack Overflow.

I was frustrated by the amount of hoops to jump through in the other answers.

So, is there a simpler way to generate an EXE file?

Comment: Which very popular questions on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is what I came up with.

I decided to write this as its own question and answer, as technically this *isn't* an answer to the question, *"How do I create a .NET Core EXE file?"*

A .NET Core portable application is a DLL file and you launch it with `dotnet yourapp.dll`, unless it's a self contained deployment, in which case you launch it with `yourapp.exe` on Windows or `./yourapp` on Linux.

This method does not try to solve that or change it.

The documentation for that is here: *[.NET Core application publishing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index)*

I've been learning how to support the new (.NET Core and Standard) and the old (.NET Framework) at the same time.

It's now become really simple.

Here's the smallest `yourapp.csproj` file for the .NET SDK:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This spits out `yourapp.dll`.

But, if you change it to:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0;net451</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

(Note the change from `<TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFrameworks>`!)

Now, when you build, in the output directory there is a `net451` and a `netcoreapp2.0` directories. In `netcoreapp2.0` there is the portable `dll` application. In the `net451` there is a normal, full framework, console `exe`.

Obviously it's not portable, but neither is the Windows EXE file created by the other methods. If you absolutely need a Windows EXE file targeting .NET Core, use the method linked at the top of the article. Of course you can use both, that's the great thing about the `TargetFrameworks` node.

Here's a Stack Overflow question which has more information about creating real .NET Core EXE files:

*[VS2017 Compile NetCoreApp as EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038847/vs2017-compile-netcoreapp-as-exe)*