# Azure Devops build pipeline doesn't build executables

Tags: azure-devops, build-pipeline, dotnetcorecli

I setup an azure build pipeline with the following Yaml

[image]

This project is a simple hello world console application, written in c# .net core 3.1

When I build or publish this project locally I get the following output:

- 146 appsettings.deploy.json
- 186 appsettings.json
- 416 TestYaml.deps.json
- 4.608 TestYaml.dll
- 171.520 TestYaml.exe
- 656 TestYaml.pdb
- 154 TestYaml.runtimeconfig.json

However, the published Artifacts through the build pipeline gives me these files:

- 140 appsettings.deploy.json
- 179 appsettings.json
- 394 TestYaml.deps.json
- 4.608 TestYaml.dll
- 86.424 TestYaml
- 632 TestYaml.pdb
- 146 TestYaml.runtimeconfig.json

So here, the file sizes are smaller, and more importantly the TestYaml.exe is missing and is replaced by a TestYaml file.

This should be rather straightforward, but I don't see what's missing.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Azure Devops build pipeline doesn't build executables

That because:

> **Executables aren't cross-platform**. They're specific to an operating system and CPU architecture. When publishing your app and
>   creating an executable, you can publish the app as self-contained or
>   **runtime-dependent**.

So, it will generate the `.dll` instead of `.exe` file when you build/publish the project with `ubuntu` agent. This dll file works across all platforms that are supported by the .net core runtime (`windows`, `linux`, `macOS`).

To generate the .exe file, you could specify the target runtime in the arguments `-r win-x64` or you can just simple to change agent to the `windows`.

Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038847/vs2017-compile-netcoreapp-as-exe) and [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you build locally on Windows and on Azure DevOps on ubuntu. If you change your pool to `windows-latest` you will get your exe file. Please take look alo here - [Build .NET Core console application to output an EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074121/build-net-core-console-application-to-output-an-exe)