# How to compile .NET (console application) in Azure DevOps and generate an exe

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I created a pipeline using the .NET desktop template and using the 'create .msi' extension but it shows a warning:

```
 ##[warning]No .MSI files were found, please check your build-configuration. If this is expected, you might consider to use the default Visual Studio Build task instead of this custom Installer task.
2018-11-28T22:58:54.1434410Z ##[section]Finishing: Create .msi file(s) from VS Installer project(s).
```

Anyone know how can I achieve creating an exe file using an Azure Pipeline and deploy it on a Virtual Machine.

Comment: Have you checked [Build your .NET desktop app for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net?view=azure-devops&tabs=vsts) or [Create a CI/CD pipeline for .NET with the Azure DevOps Project](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azuredevopsprojectdotnet/)?

Comment: @rickvdbosch yes but I want to create exe(setup) file using azure pipeline ?

Comment: An `.exe` and a setup file are not the same. An `.exe` is an executable file, the program to run. A setup is only needed if you want to distribute this program for instance over the internet and you think a zip won't cut it. For you to publish this application to a VM is as easy as copying the output folder to the VM. Tip: start with a pipeline that successfully builds the executable and then take the next step.

Comment: @rickvdbosch sir which step I need to follow can you explain me because pipeline is run but .exe file is not create and I need to create .exe and run on VM.

Comment: @rickvdbosch I also try to copy that artifacts to VM and artifacts are copied but I am uable to run application on that vm its show missing some dependencies files..i don't know why

Answer (score 15):

> If you use [.NET Core CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) to build your console app.

Below dotnet publish arguements commmand will generate .exe file. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038847/vs2017-compile-netcoreapp-as-exe) for more information.

`dotnet publish -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=True --self-contained false`

So you can add above arguments to your .NET Core CLI task. See below yaml pipeline.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish 
    arguments: -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=True --self-contained false -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    publishWebProjects: false
  enabled: true
```

Above DotNetCoreCLI task will output the .exe file to folder `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` (ie. `C:\agent\_work\1\a`)

> If you use [Visual Studio Build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops) to build your console app.

You can first add below `<PublishSingleFile>` and `<RuntimeIdentifier>`  properties to the .csproj file of your  project.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <PublishSingleFile>True</PublishSingleFile>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then set the **msbuildArgs** of the Visual Studio Build task in your pipeline as below:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: '/t:publish /p:PublishSingleFile=True /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64 /p:outputpath=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\'
```

Then Vsbuild task will output the .exe file to folder `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` specified in `/p:outputpath` (ie. `C:\agent\_work\1\a`)

Comment: How about for .NET Framework and not .NET Core?

Comment: I know you asked this ages ago, but MSBuild.exe "Project.csproj" "/p:Configuration=Release" "/p:OutDir=C:\tmp\outputdrop\\"