# .NET Core 31 - Single EXE - The application to execute does not exist

Tags: .net-core

Converted an old .NET Framework project to .NET Core 3.1 yesterday. The application runs fine on my own machine and debugs correctly.

I have put both the following into my .vbproj/.csproj

```
<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win81-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

However when I move the .EXE to a remote machine and attempt to run said EXE on that remote machine I get told that the DLL (for the project in question) does not exists.

I moved the .dll to the same directory that the exe is in (not ideal) and get the following error instead

```
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'.
```

I used to use Costura.Fody to create a single file exe without any issues in .NET Framework, I was under the impression the above would do the same for the .NET Core packages.

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: try to publish as self-contained?

Comment: I assume .NET Core 3.1 is installed on the target machine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compile a .NET Core application as an EXE file using Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038847/compile-a-net-core-application-as-an-exe-file-using-visual-studio-2017)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone else that may find this question and find it useless.

I was 'Building' the project instead of 'Publishing' the project, this in-turn wasn't creating the self-contained exe properly.

Don't be a donut like me.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019, go to Build > Publish MyApp. This will open a tab in the editor area. Click on Show all settings to open the Profile settings dialog. Then click on File publish options and check Produce single file.