# C# Visual Studio 2017 package app into a single .exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, executable

I searched in the last couple of days for a way to package my whole application (VS project) into a single .exe file. This project has a zip folder as a resource, what I want to achieve is this:

1. Build an .exe file including all dependencies (7zip, .NET, zip folder resource, etc)
2. Send the .exe file to a remote customer
3. Once the customer runs the .exe, the zip file should be put in the path I decided upon in my project.

I could not understand how to do it. I saw multiple answers about running the Publish option but it does not work nor do I have the options they are suggesting.

See here [Publish with VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52443448/14438633)

Comment: What version of .Net does your project target. This might be a .NET (Core) thing and not work with .NET Framework.

Comment: Not sure how to check but if I run dotnet --version from my project folder I get 2.1.520

Comment: @GiladDahan That's very outdated. Self-Contained publishing has been significantly improved with .NET 5.0. (Note that that alone won't give you a single exe file, though)

Comment: So what should I do to get what I need?

Comment: Try this method and see if it works:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using ILMerge to pack my exe with other dlls

https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge

The script at the end helped me create an automated process for this