# Visual Studio 2017 - How to get the "New publisher Wizard"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, web-publishing

I have a problem with publishing an app in VS 2017 with the Publishing Wizard. I found a stackoverflow post:

[Compile a .NET Core application as an EXE file using Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038847/compile-a-net-core-application-as-an-exe-file-using-visual-studio-2017/44039013#44039013)

But when I want to go to this menu it only opens an old Publishing Wizard that doesnt have the options I need.

I tried to update my VS 2017 to the newest Version, but it didnt help...

After that I tried to use the first approach of the stackoverflow post above, but I didnt have dotnet(???) so installed .NET 7 SDK. Tried the command in the project directory (where the .csproject lays), but I got the error: MSB4062. So Im back trying to get the new publisher, because I really dont know how to fix MSB4062.

Picture of my Publishing wizard:[image: my Publishing wizard]

Picture of the one I want:
[[image: my Publishing wizard]]

Comment: You need to convert your ASP/ASP.NET/WebAPI **.NET Framework** _x.y_ project to the equivalent **.NET Core 3.x** / **.NET 5+**.

Comment: Do you know a way to do that?

Comment: Also, IIRC to get that dialog you also need at least VS2019. When you work with .NET 7.0 you need VS2022 Preview.

Comment: Hi, have you got any updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed a **.NET Core / .NET** console app, but I had a *.NET FRAMEWORK* console app.
And to create a **.NET Core / .NET** console app I needed **Visual Studio 2022 (maybe 2019 is enough)**, but I had *Visual Studio 2017*.

This fixed everything for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Publish Wizard is usually the first time you publish a project and will guide you to publish the project to the specified location.

[image]

After completing the Publish Wizard, you will find Publish Settings in the Publish view and configure it. Hope it can help you

[image]