# Deploy .NET Core 2 Console App

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, publish

I would like to publish .NET Core 2 with Visual Studio 2017 15.4 – I have created console app and do only Console.Write and Read for test purpose. Next I would like to publish this for windows so I have changed project properties to:

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

When I’m trying to do publish with default stings I have and error “Publish failed” and output have this error “Could not copy the file "obj\x64\Release\netcoreapp2.0\win10-x64\ConsoleApp6.dll" because it was not found.”
Another thing is that I can find exe in “bin\x64\Release\netcoreapp2.0\win10-x64” but after run there is no text I have written in my app but I can see “host-options:” and couple of options?

I don't know why error occurs and why  I see “host-options:” after run the app?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I am having the same error.

Comment: Nope - For now I'm using publish from command line without change to project config like in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074121/build-net-core-console-application-to-output-an-exe

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug when using custom folders for different platforms with publishing. I have the same issue.
The error indicates that it searches the `ConsoleApp6.dll` in the path `obj\x64\Release\netcoreapp2.0\win10-x64`.
But in my case, the .dll file was in `obj\x64\Release\netcoreapp2.0\`.

My workaround was to copy the .dll file manually to `obj\x64\Release\netcoreapp2.0\win10-x64` (and other platform folders) and then publish the app again.

This also resolves the "host-options:" problem you mentioned when running the app. This simply appears because it could not publish / build it successfully for the given platform.