# .Net Core, Web App Executes Console App

Tags: c#, web, .net-core, console-application

I have a .net 2 Core web app on windows IIS. No issues with the web app. How can I successfully run:

**1)** a .net core console app;and

**2)** a regular windows executable?

The console app is needed because of the work passed to it can take several minutes - sometimes up to 10 minutes to complete. Probably too long to expect a user to keep their browser open.

I have tried using `"System.Diagnostics.Process"` on the windows app with much success. I figured before I started trying with the Core app, I would get some suggestions. Let me know if any additional information is needed.

Comment: I have a web app that send text =, voice or email notifications to residents of various buildings in downtown Chicago. The web app pushes the task to a console app that actually does the sending. Once the console app is activated, the web  app can go on to other things=.

Comment: Hangfire is your friend

Answer (score 2):

Console app in .net core 2 has a lot of new features in it, explaining it in a nutshell is a little bit complicated.

I would suggest starting from this

- [guide](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/Getting-started-with-.NET-Core-2---Console-application)

  on git hub which sums it up really good.

I would also recommend looking into this post regarding [Windows Executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074121/build-net-core-console-application-to-output-an-exe?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) (which is about .net core 1.0 but is more or less the same) and this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2016/10/11/net-core-how-to-publish-a-self-contained-application-exe/).

Those will be a good place for you to start.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this will be useful, But you can try the task scheduler to call the app. Gets rid of a lot of permission problems.

Comment: What does this has to do with the question?

Comment: The question was an alternative way to run console apps from webapps right? So use the webapps to call the task scheduler to run the console app. This was the idea, stupid, but can avoid a lot of configurations.