# Deploying C# Program as a Command Line Utility

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface

I wrote a pretty simple program in C# to automatically generate csv files of a specific format from data from other spreadsheets, and I'd like to deploy it as a command line interface utility, i.e a `.exe` file that can be run outside of VS Code, the IDE I'm using. I have the dotnet sdk tools installed, and I tried using `dotnet msbuild` with the .csproj file below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

The command `dotnet msbuild` in the terminal built into VS Code generates a folder in `bin` called `release` that contains a `.dll` file, but not a `.exe` file. What parameters can I add to `dotnet msbuild` to generate a `.exe` file, or do I have to use another tool?

EDIT: I checked [Build .NET Core console application to output an EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074121/build-net-core-console-application-to-output-an-exe)

and tried `dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64` and got this error: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

SOLUTION: msbuild was the wrong tool to use-- I believe csc is the correct tool, as it created an application file.

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking how to create an `exe` or how to make it available from any command line window, like `ping` utility?

Comment: @AleksAndreev Both ideally

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build .NET Core console application to output an EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074121/build-net-core-console-application-to-output-an-exe)

Comment: Core apps can be run with `dotnet [your_app].dll`. Otherwise you can go through a little extra work to get an .exe, but it's not typically necessary.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I'm assuming the user won't have the dotnet sdk installed since I had to install it specifically to write this program.

Comment: @JackHannum - You should post a self answer instead of editing it into the posted question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

msbuild was the wrong tool to use-- I believe csc is the correct tool, as it created an application file.