# How to run .NET core application by double clicking a file like exe in .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

In .NET framework when we build our solution/project, we get an exe in the debug/release folder and we can run our application by double clicking that exe. But how can we do this in .NET core, i know we can't have an exe in .NET core because it is windows specific. When i build my .NET core application i get the following files in the debug folder.[image]

I know how to run this application using command prompt but i want to have a file like exe by clicking which i can run my application.

Comment: Use the [Process.Start() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-do-i-start-a-process-from-c)

Comment: Can you provide me a bit more information @KunalMukherjee

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build .NET Core console application to output an EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074121/build-net-core-console-application-to-output-an-exe)

Answer (score 3):

You can generate exe (self-contained application).

.NET Core 2.0 +
Open Package Manager Console or any other console in your project directory and type:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64
dotnet publish -c Release -r ubuntu.16.10-x64
```

When you use previous version of .NET Core you have to add runtime identifier of the target environment in csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;ubuntu.16.10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Runtime Identifiers (RIDs) list:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog

Comment: Please use `linux-x64` instead of an os-specific RID like `ubuntu.16.10-x64`. The first one will run on all new-ish linux distributions. The second wont even run on the next version of ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to create a .bat file with runs the dll via the dotnet cli, then you get "*a file like exe*"

```
dotnet ConsoleApp2.dll
```