# How to publish my WPF solution with Rider?

Tags: c#, wpf, publish, rider

I cannot seem to deploy my WPF app using the Rider IDE. Most support tell me to use the "Publish" button in VS which of course doesn't really help me.

I do produce an executable with the *.NET Project* and *.NET Executable* build Configurations, but it doesn't seem to run on any other machine, where it seems to close immediately without spitting error messages (even from PowerShell)

N.B. the app launches fine from my own machine, and from anywhere I choose to move it to.

I've tried to set `Edit Configurations...` > `Runtime arguments:` to

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64
```

as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44074296/11136955), but that wasn't enough.

Running `dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64 .\my_app.csproj` from PowerShell returns

```
error MSB4216: Impossible to execute the task "GenerateResource" 
[...] 
Failed to connect to "CLR4" runtime and the "x86" architecture.
Make sure that
(1) The necessary runtime and/or architecture is present on the machine
(2) "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\<version>\MSBuild.exe" exists and 
    has permissions to execute.
```

Now MSBuild is missing from that folder, but there is MSBuild.dll there.

Am I really missing a fool-proof easy way of publishing a C# WPF solution with Rider?

Answer (score 0):

I use https://wixtoolset.org/ to publish my apps. It's free and independent of the IDE...

Comment: @mcy - yes, it is not really easy, but it is worth it. It is supported by msbuild and (once it is done) you can also use it in automated build processes quit easily.