# How do I package my C# Basic console application in just an EXE file?

Tags: c#, console-application, exe

I have a console application that does basic output and calculations. 
I am trying to create the application and have just a .EXE file that you can open and use the application.
I have tried publishing it in visual studio and just get a lot of dll files with a exe that has to be in the same folder?

Any help?

Comment: For .net core see https://stackoverflow.com/q/44074121/1260204 as possible duplicate

Comment: You could have choosed "Console App (.Net Framework)" when creating new project, there would be exe-file inside Bin folder, which you can simply copy. This is assuming it's *basic* (e.g. no nugets).

Answer (score -3):

After building the project, a "bin" directory is created in the project folder. There is a subfolder for "Debug" and "Release", depending on the build configuration you chose. In that folder there is your .exe file which you can copy and pass around like any executable.

Comment: Consider re-reading the question.  You're answering a different problem here, I think.