# What is the content of .Net publish resulting exe?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I published a small C# .Net Core 2.2 console application as executable using the following command from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074121/build-net-core-console-application-to-output-an-exe):

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64
```

The generated files contain both the classic ConsoleApp.dll, but also the executable that I was expecting to be generated ConsoleApp.exe.

My question is why there was still the DLL generated, since all its code, *I suppose*, could have been compiled to the .exe, as in a .Net Framework application?

On the other hand, I tried to decompile the .exe file with [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) but the content from it does not seem to be managed code. In this case I also suppose that the .exe file is just calling the DLL using the `dotnet` command. Is this assumption right?

Below is the Console Application .csproj file content:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Management" Version="4.7.0-preview3.19551.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="input.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Are using the latest .NET Core 3? Is `PublishTrimmed` enabled?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I am using .Net Core 2.2 from VS 2017.

Comment: Could you please share your `csproj` file?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I have added it in the question.

Comment: Well, you have an additional reference. Also why you haven't specified `--self-contained true`?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I have removed the additional reference, and I don't actually want to create a self contained application. I am asking about the behavior of `dotnet publish` in this particular case and the generated .exe and .dll.

Comment: When you publish a self-contained deployment (SCD), the .NET Core SDK creates a platform-specific executable - this is an exe, dll is your app actually, have a look at [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli)

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question. I'll try to cover it as much as I possibly can.

With the introduction of .net core 3.0 came the [Single file publish](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/single-file/design.md) as described in the design documentation of .Net. So If you have a .net 3.0 application then you can use the  `/p:PublishSingleFile=true` to bundle everything in a single executable.

Watch out for the `/p:PublishTrimmed=true` option, as treeshaking can and probably will cause problems with reflection code, as access to it is not covered by the tree shaking.

For previous versions of net core, you need to use one of the packagers like [wrap](https://github.com/dgiagio/warp) or [Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura).

As per the exe file, I'll mention somthing from the wrap documentation:

> The final self-contained single binary application consists of two
>   parts: 1) runner and 2) the compressed target application executable
>   and dependencies.

The dll that is created by the standard publisher is multi platform and non specific to windows. So the executable file has all the code needed to create the process in windows and call the actual code that is in the dll that can be used on any platform. It's just a wrapper.

[image: Wrap application]

More information about the executable [Microsoft .net core deploying docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/)

> Self-contained deployment. Unlike FDD, a self-contained deployment
>   (SCD) doesn't rely on the presence of shared components on the target
>   system. All components, including both the .NET Core libraries and the
>   .NET Core runtime, are included with the application and are isolated
>   from other .NET Core applications. SCDs include an executable (such as
>   app.exe on Windows platforms for an application named app), which is a
>   renamed version of the platform-specific .NET Core host, and a .dll
>   file (such as app.dll), which is the actual application.

Comment: But the question is about .NET Core 2.2

Comment: Check https://github.com/dgiagio/warp#windows-1 for .net core 2.2

Comment: *the executable file has all the code needed to create the process in windows and call the actual code that is in the dll* - is this also the case for the .exe and .dll resulting after the `dotnet publish` command in .Net Core 2.2?

Comment: It is, for all net core applications. All your actual application code will be included in the dll file, in a way that you can use the dll file even without the exe.

Comment: Check the updated answer for more documentation about the exe file (from the official microsoft documentation)

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras I have read that part of the documentation, but I believe it is more about the self contained deployment and it focuses on the fact that the components of the .Net Core runtime are included into the application, so it will not rely on the presence of .Net Core runtime on the target machine. What I haven't seen on the MSDN is what actually this .exe is doing and whether it's only calling the DLL or not.

Comment: Your answer is the one that comes closest to the actual question. I just want to see some reference of what is the .exe file doing in the current deployment.

Comment: I started a new github question to get some official answer as I couldn't find any more information other than what I included in the question, so I can only make assumptions from here: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/15986 I will let you know as soon as I've got some extra information. Thanks for the great question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your assumption. But use the following command it will generate only two files, one is .exe and other is .pdb in the publish directory inside win10-x64 directory.

```
dotnet publish -r win10-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true
```

Comment: I am using .Net Core 2.2 to publish. Are the arguments you used in your commands specific to .Net Core 3? I am asking because I still get generated both the DLL and the exe.