# How to run a C# project I downloaded?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies

This an exercising project I downloaded from Pluralsight. I tried to run dotnet restore & dotnet build on folder CARS. It does not seem to work. 
The "Program" dependency just showed "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug//.dll" when I just got it. I tried to modify it a bit, but it didn't work.

Visual studio code tells me that I may want to have something like ""program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Cars.dll"," But I don't seem a dll file inside the debug folder

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I highly recommend Visual Studio for working with C# projects. It's a lot better integrated.

Comment: Do you have all the necessary extensions installed for C# development? I found it a little bit ... "inconvenient". Maybe try Visual Studio Community Edition.

Comment: have you tried running cars.exe in the debug folder?

Comment: @Josh I had and the program just shut itself down

Comment: @Fildor I did. I have built a few personal projects using C# already.

Comment: Is this an "add implementation here"-exercise project or an "this is what it should look like" exercise project?

Comment: If you want to build an .exe, you must generate a self contained application (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074121/build-net-core-console-application-to-output-an-exe). Otherwise you should build a .dll and run it from command line using dotnet.

Comment: @stl I already have built an .exe using dotnet build. How do I build a .dll? What command do I execute?

Comment: @Fildor the project itself already has some features implemented. And it should work. I just don't seem to able to run or debug it..

Comment: @Fildor so the project works on VS, but VS code

Comment: @FangyiLi execute it via the command line, not windows