# How to run a dotnet console app from the command line using an alias

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, command-line, command-line-interface

I know how to do this with batch files, you add the path to the system variable but I cannot seem to find the answer to my question anywhere.
Anyone knows?

example:
Instead of navigating to the app directory and running
`dotnet run` I would like to just call a command like `myApp` from any directory I'm in.

PS: Im using windows 10.

Comment: compile it and add it to your path

Answer (score 1):

you can just use a shell alias if you work on cmd

```
doskey runMyApp=dotnet run path\to\my\app
```

more info given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/doskey)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know which folders are in your path environment variable. You can see those if you go to ControlPanel/System/Advanced settings/Environment Variables

So, you either use one of the existing folders, or you add a new folder.

After that, you can can compile your dotnet core program to a .exe file. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074121/build-net-core-console-application-to-output-an-exe) for details on how to do that.