# How to hide console window in Gtk# Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net-core, gtk#

I created Gtk# application using this code

Program.cs

```
using System;
using Gtk;

namespace projects
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init();

            var app = new Application("org.projects.projects", GLib.ApplicationFlags.None);
            app.Register(GLib.Cancellable.Current);

            var win = new MainWindow();
            app.AddWindow(win);

            win.Show();
            Application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.cs

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using UI = Gtk.Builder.ObjectAttribute;

namespace projects
{
    class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [UI] private Label _label1 = null;
        [UI] private Button _button1 = null;

        private int _counter;

        public MainWindow() : this(new Builder("MainWindow.glade")) { }

        private MainWindow(Builder builder) : base(builder.GetRawOwnedObject("MainWindow"))
        {
            builder.Autoconnect(this);

            DeleteEvent += Window_DeleteEvent;
            _button1.Clicked += Button1_Clicked;
        }

        private void Window_DeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }

        private void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs a)
        {
            _counter++;
            _label1.Text = "Hello World! This button has been clicked " + _counter + " time(s).";
        }
    }
}
```

projects.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="**\*.glade" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.glade">
      <LogicalName>%(Filename)%(Extension)</LogicalName>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="GtkSharp" Version="3.24.24.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

but the problem the application is showing command line console then it's showing a window like this

[image: console with a pop up window]

I want to just showing the window application without command line console. I already using this WinExe but this does not work on dotnet core 6.0. I build this project using the following command:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o publish -p:PublishReadyToRun=true -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:PublishTrimmed=true --self-contained true -p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true -p:EnableCompressionInSingleFile=true
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the compiler is not setting the executable subsystem flag correctly as set in the `<OutputType>` option in the .csproj file (`WinExe` should produce a GUI executable, `Exe` should build a console executable). I ended up using the PE editor in [this tool](https://github.com/petoolse/petools) to change it to `Windows GUI` instead of `Windows console`.

Not very elegant and wish there was a way to automate it, but it's the only way i could find.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm newbie. how do i use this PE editor to change from console app to windows gui app? Thanks

Comment: In the menu: `Tools` -> `PE editor`, open your exe, in the new dialog click on a button on the right called called  `Optional Header`, then look for `Subsystem` around the middle of the right column, click on `...` and change it to Windows GUI.